# Bootstrap modal não carrega Google Maps v3 corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

[image: Imagem de erro]

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema, ao carregar Google Maps v3 em um Modal com o Framework Bootstrap o mapa não é exibido corretamente.

Segue o código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 400px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn">Open modal</a>

        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mapmodals">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title">Peggy Guggenheim Collection - Venice</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->     

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

        <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#mapmodals").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            });

            $("#openBtn").click(function () {
                $('#mapmodals').modal('show');
            });
        });

        var map;

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78y59fso/) com exemplo do erro.

Comment: Montei um JSFiddle pra você que reproduz o comportamento: http://jsfiddle.net/h4d5006f/.

Comment: Wakim, no JSFiddle que você montou não tem o Modal.

Comment: Atualizei, vê denovo, acabei esquecendo de dar `fork` antes.

Comment: Wakim, agora está exatamente como na imagem a cima que postei, ou seja, com o erro, o mapa não renderiza no model. Sabe alguma possível solução ?

Comment: Editei sua resposta com alguns acertos, se me permite. Inclui o link do JSFiddle para que não precisem procurar nos comentários.

Comment: Sem problema. No exemplo que você montou no JSFiddle se selecionar um lugar pelo Street View ele renderiza e fica tudo certo, faz o teste.

Comment: Eu acho que o `resize` vai funcionar, mas o evento de `shown.bs.modal` não esta sendo chamado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17417/discussion-between-pedro-a-and-wakim).

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que estava executando o `bind` antes do `DOM` ter sido construído por completo. Logo o seletor `$('#mapmodals')` não estava trazendo nenhum elemento e por isso não chamava a função definida para o evento, que redimensionava o `#map-canvas`.

Para isso, englobei o código de inicialização dos eventos dentro de um `ready` do jQuery.

O código ficou:

```
// Pode usar o document.ready também:
//$(document).ready(function() { ... });

$(function () {
    // Esse trecho de codigo sera executado quando a construção do DOM for terminada. Possibilitando a localização dos elementos nos seletores.
    $("#mapmodals").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
});

var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkvw4skn/) com a correção.

Comment: Copiei igual o seu exemplo que resolveu, mas não sei o porque agora não está exibindo nada.

Comment: Já descobri o possível erro. Está executando o `$('#mapmodals").on(...);` antes do documento ser carregado, logo o seletor estava vazio. Vou atualizar minha resposta. Agora faz sentido não funcionar.

Comment: Fiz igual o JSFiddle e nada ainda.

Comment: Se a solução não deu certo é preciso mais informações de onde esta aplicando. Se puder coloque o restante do html. Esta gerando algum erro no console?

Comment: Editei a pergunta inserindo a página toda.

Comment: Qual versão do `Bootstrap` esta usando? Fiz o `JSFiddle` com a versão 3.1.1. Não falta importar o arquivo javascript do `Bootstrap`?

Comment: Eu importei o Boostrap, olha lá no código.